# Why am I receiving a 502 error when attempting to communicate with my Node.js backend through Nginx after updating my frontend on an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am running an nginx web server on an AWS EC2 instance
On the same instance I am running a frontend web application (reactjs) (port 3000) and a backend nodejs server (port 3002)
Everything was working correctly until I made an update in my frontend and now I am unable to send requests to my backend (either from the api requests in the frontend or using curl). When I do make requests, I get a 502 error.
I have checked that there are no firewalls prohibiting access to my backend
The backend is running but is not logging any requests when I send one to it
Can you help me work out why I am unable to send requests to my backend, and instead getting 502 errors?

NGINX:

```
server {
    server_name abc.co.uk;

    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name abc.co.uk;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.co.uk/full_chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.co.uk/private_key.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
}
```

Backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan'); 
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3002;

const accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join('./', 'access.log'), { flags: 'a' });

app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: accessLogStream }));

// Retrieve SSL certificate and key file paths
const readCertificates = async () => {
  try {
    const sslPrivKeyPath = './private_key_path;
    const sslFullChainPath = './full_chain_path;

    const key = fs.readFileSync(sslPrivKeyPath, 'utf8');
    const cert = fs.readFileSync(sslFullChainPath, 'utf8');

    return { key, cert };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error reading SSL certificates:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const logRequests = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Incoming request: ${req.method} ${req.originalUrl}`);
  next();
};

const logErrors = (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error('Error encountered:', err);
  next(err);
};

const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  if (!res.headersSent) {
    res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
  }
};

app.use(logErrors);
app.use(errorHandler);

app.use(logRequests);

  app.get('/exampleapi', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const apiKey = 123
      res.json({
        apiKey
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching parameters:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
    }
  });

const startServer = async () => {
  try {
    const httpsOptions = await readCertificates();

    const httpsServer = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app);

    httpsServer.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
      console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error starting the server:', error);
  }
};

startServer();
```

Frontend:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const getRequest = async () => {
  try {
    await fetchPublicIPv4();
    const response = await axios.get(`https://abc.co.uk/api/exampleapi`);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching config:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

I get this error in my NGINX log when I make the request:

signal process started
signal 1 (SIGHUP) received from 123, reconfiguring
reconfiguring
using the "epoll" event method
start worker processes
start worker process 123
gracefully shutting down
exiting
exit
signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 2037217
worker process 123 exited with code 0
signal 29 (SIGIO) received
*14 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 12.34.56.78, server: abc.co.uk, request: "GET /api/exampleapi HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3002/api/exampleapi", host: "abc.co.uk", referrer: "https://abc.co.uk/"

I have attempted restarting all of the individual servers, re-uploading all of the code to my EC2 instance
I have added timeout limits to my proxy routes